# Terraform fails to import key pair with Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Using Terraform 0.7.7.

I have a simple Terraform file with the following:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "personal" {
  ami           = "${lookup(var.amis, var.region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.personal.id}"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "personal" {
  key_name = "mschuchard-us-east"
  public_key = "${var.public_key}"
}
```

`Terraform apply` yields the following error:

```
aws_key_pair.personal: Creating...
  fingerprint: "" => "<computed>"
  key_name:    "" => "mschuchard-us-east"
  public_key:  "" => "ssh-rsa pubkey hash mschuchard-us-east"
aws_instance.personal: Creating...
  ami:                      "" => "ami-c481fad3"
  availability_zone:        "" => "<computed>"
  ebs_block_device.#:       "" => "<computed>"
  ephemeral_block_device.#: "" => "<computed>"
  instance_state:           "" => "<computed>"
  instance_type:            "" => "t2.micro"
  key_name:                 "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface_id:     "" => "<computed>"
  placement_group:          "" => "<computed>"
  private_dns:              "" => "<computed>"
  private_ip:               "" => "<computed>"
  public_dns:               "" => "<computed>"
  public_ip:                "" => "<computed>"
  root_block_device.#:      "" => "<computed>"
  security_groups.#:        "" => "<computed>"
  source_dest_check:        "" => "true"
  subnet_id:                "" => "<computed>"
  tenancy:                  "" => "<computed>"
  vpc_security_group_ids.#: "" => "<computed>"
aws_instance.personal: Creation complete
aws_eip.ip: Creating...
  allocation_id:     "" => "<computed>"
  association_id:    "" => "<computed>"
  domain:            "" => "<computed>"
  instance:          "" => "i-0ab94b58b0089697d"
  network_interface: "" => "<computed>"
  private_ip:        "" => "<computed>"
  public_ip:         "" => "<computed>"
  vpc:               "" => "<computed>"
aws_eip.ip: Creation complete
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_key_pair.personal: Error import KeyPair: InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair 'mschuchard-us-east' already exists.
status code: 400, request id: 51950b9a-55e8-4901-bf35-4d2be234abbf
```

The only help I found with googling was to blow away the `*.tfstate` files, which I tried and that did not help. I can launch an EC2 instance with the gui with this key pair and easily ssh into it, but Terraform is erroring when trying to use the same fully functional keypair.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is telling you that the keypair already exists in your AWS account but Terraform has no knowledge of it in its state files so is attempting to create it each time.

You have two options available to you here. Firstly, you could simply delete it from the AWS account and allow Terraform to upload it and thus allow it to be managed by Terraform and be in its state files.

Alternatively you could use the Terraform `import` command to import the pre-existing resource into your state file:

```
terraform import aws_key_pair.personal mschuchard-us-east
```

Comment: In my case it would be `aws_key_pair.personal` for the import. Anyway, after fighting with the credentials for some time and giving up on getting Terraform to use a credentials file, I successfully imported and ran `terraform apply`. Then I realized what the resource was actually doing and how to associate a `key_name` with the instance. Terraform is so user-unfriendly and really needs more advanced tutorials. Make the edit to the import command and I will accept this answer.

Comment: Also staring at the EC2 instance dashboard made me realize I also need `vpc_security_group_ids`. Now I can actually successfully ssh into EC2 instances created by Terraform, but the output from `${aws_instance.personal.public_dns}` is completely inaccurate, so I have one more bang-head-against-wall session in front of me.

Answer (score 8):

Use the ${uuid()} function to always get a random id for key pairs when generating, the selected/generated UUID makes it into the state file, so you will still be able to delete, but updating will not be possible. Every time you apply your terraform file there will be a new keypair generated...

While it is true that you can not generate a key pair from scratch using the AWS provider, you can generate a new key pair object in AWS using an RSA private key that the TLS provider generates.

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "test" {
    key_name   = "${uuid()}"
    public_key = "${tls_private_key.t.public_key_openssh}"
}
provider "tls" {}
resource "tls_private_key" "t" {
    algorithm = "RSA"
}
provider "local" {}
resource "local_file" "key" {
    content  = "${tls_private_key.t.private_key_pem}"
    filename = "id_rsa"
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "chmod 600 id_rsa"
    }
}
```

Use the tls provider to generate a key, and import it as a new object every time.
Then export the private key so that you have it for access to the server(s) later on.

It is worthy to note that this breaks one of the paradigms that Terraform is attempting to use (infrastructure as code), but from a practical development standpoint that might be a bit too idealistic... Terraform builds fail midway through and states get invalidated. A better solution might be if the AWS plugin received an "already exists" error it imported automatically, or if that was an optional behavior that could be set.

Answer (score 5):

The error says that key pair already exists in AWS, and it does not say whether it was created using Terraform or using console.

You should see it in AWS console `EC2 -> Key Pairs` for correct region. You should delete it using console before retrying import it using Terraform.

Comment: Wait, according to this https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/key_pair.html I cannot create a key pair using Terraform. Also, if I delete the key pair from within the console, how would I know the public key to specify it inside Terraform?

Comment: Correct, you can't create EC2 key pairs using Terraform, but you can create it locally (keep it secretly) and get public key from it (`ssh-keygen -y -f myssh.key > myssh.pub`), which you can put into resource `aws_key_pair `.

Comment: deleting the key is not a solution. If this is just one resource in your config and you have EC2's that depend on this, there needs to be a solution without removing it

Comment: It does work for me. After deleting the keypair from EC2 ,-> Key Pairs, i was able to spinup the instance.