# Key Issues with AWS, Ansible, and Terraform

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform

I'm writing a program that uses Terraform to create an instance of a VM on Amazon EC2, and then runs an Ansible script at the instance to do further configuration. The program does the following:

1. Generate a RSA public/private key pair
2. Via python's `subprocess` module, run `terraform apply` on a prepared json file, passing in the generated public key and other information.
3. Capture the hostname(s) from the output of that call
4. Use `subprocess` to run an Ansible playbook targeting that host, and given the generated private key.

However, the Ansible script is failing to connect to the host. The error message implies key issues are to blame:

```
ec2-user@ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

but after double-checking the public key used to generate the instance and the private key used to connect, I confirmed that they do match. I have a feeling the issue is some encoding thing, but I could use help figuring out where.

I can confirm that the VM are created successfully - I can see them in the EC2 console.

---

The following method is what generates the key pair:

```
def generate_ssh_key():
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        backend=crypto_default_backend(),
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048)

    private_key = key.private_bytes(
        crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        crypto_serialization.NoEncryption())

    public_key = key.public_key().public_bytes(
        crypto_serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH,
        crypto_serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH)

    return str(public_key, "utf-8"), str(private_key, "utf-8")
```

---

The relevant lines in my `aws.tf.json` file are:

```
  "resource": {
    "aws_key_pair": {
      "generated_key": {
        "key_name": "aws-key-${var.id}",
        "public_key": "${var.public_key}"
      }
    }
  },

 "resource": {
   "aws_instance": {
     "vm": {
       ...
       "key_name": "${aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name}",
       ...
     }
   }
 }
```

where `id` and `public_key` were passed in as variables on the command line. `aws_key_pair` was not.

---

The `subprocess` arguments to `terraform apply` look like this:

```
['terraform', 'apply', '-auto-approve', '-var', 'public_key=ssh-rsa AAAA...', '-var', 'user_id=...', '-var', 'access_key=...', '-var', 'secret_key=...']
```

And the `subprocess` arguments to `ansible-playbook` look like this (I'm using a `tempfile` to print the private key. I've tried writing it to tempfile in mode `w` and mode `wb`, and neither worked):

```
['ansible-playbook', '--private-key=/path/to/tempfile.pem', '-i', 'ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com,', '-e', 'hostname=ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com', '-e', ...]
```

A lot of the code involved in this (most of the terraform stuff) was written by my teammates, so I don't entirely know how all of it works. If there's anything else I need to provide I'll try to find it

Comment: What happens if you try to SSH into the instance with the generated key? What user are you trying to SSH into the instance as? And what is your base AMI, eg. Ubuntu/Amazon Linux etc?

Comment: The base AMI is Amazon Linux. I'm sshing in as `ec2-user`, but then setting ansible to `become=true` so that it runs everything as root. Trying to ssh manually using the same tempfile as the ansible script uses produced the same error message.

Comment: Check the content of variable public_key once. Make sure there aren't any extra white spaces because everything else seems correct.

Comment: No, according to `terraform apply`'s output, there's only the one space in the public key. The private key might have an extra line break at the end, after the `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` line, but would that cause the issue?

Comment: Your Python code isn't a complete example so it's hard to see what you might be doing wrong here. Out of curiosity is there a reason you're generating SSH keys on the fly like this? And is there a reason you're not doing all of this directly with Terraform to generate the SSH keys like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792833/2291321) and running Ansible as a `local-exec` provisioner? Or even just doing this as a shell script instead of just constantly shelling out and not doing anything useful in Python directly?

Comment: Python is used because this is run as part of a python microservice. The keys are generated on the fly because they need to be different for each instance, and can't just be prepared in advance. Generating the SSH keys with Terraform and running Ansible as a local-exec provisioner might be possible; I'll investigate that

Answer (score 0):

(OP)

Turns out the question was wrong in the first place. I was using the wrong user account - while I had expected EC2 to create amazon-linux VMs, as that's what they did when I manually tested the system beforehand, my teammate actually set them up to create ubuntu VMs. So the username `ec2-user` I was using was the cause of the problem - changed it to `ubuntu` and it worked (by which I mean I got a different error, but that was easier to debug).