# Terraform: can't remote-exec on a compute engine VM with generated SSH key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, ssh-keys, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to remotely execute some commands on a freshly provisioned Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM using ssh keys with Terraform. Here's my code:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "ssh-key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "static-content" {

  # ...

  metadata {
    sshKeys = "root:${tls_private_key.ssh-key.public_key_openssh}"
  }

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "root"
    private_key = "${tls_private_key.ssh-key.private_key_pem}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "curl -L https://github.com/aelsabbahy/goss/releases/download/v0.3.6/goss-linux-amd64 -o ~/goss",
      "chmod +x ~/goss",
      "~/goss -g ~/gossfile.yml validate",
    ]
  }

}
```

The output I get in the Terraform apply is

```
google_compute_instance.static-content: Still creating... (2m10s elapsed)
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   Host: 35.198.166.131
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   User: root
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   Password: false
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   Private key: true
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
google_compute_instance.static-content (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
```

So it seems like the ssh key is not properly propagated to the VM. Any hints why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you just tried it in a different way, give it a try with below code which worked for me

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
connection {
type = "ssh"
port = 22
user = "username"
agent = "false"
private_key = "${file("/path/to/your/pem_file")}"
}
 inline = [
 "your command goes here",
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: It's a generated SSH key (like with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792833/2291321) not one that's sat on the user's file system.

Comment: I tried this way before and it didn't work either. Seems like the problem was trying to ssh into the machine as `root` which seems to be not allowed. When I changed to the `gcp` user and used `sudo` to run the commands, everything worked as expected. Thank you anyways!