# AWS and Terraform: Invalid Key Pair response, but it absolutely exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is really stumping me. I am teaching the basics of Terraform to a small class, and wrote and tested a Lab that just makes a simple aws_instance resource, specifying a key_name that they pre-create in the Console, so that they can use the associated private key to SSH into the instance after Terraform's done. It's worked for everyone except for one student, who is getting the following error:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'access-key-pair' does not exist
```

I've checked that `access-key-pair` absolutely exists under EC2 > Key Pairs in the student's account, we're in the same Region as is specified in `provider.tf`, there's no typos in the code... why is the AWS API telling Terraform that the key doesn't exist when we can quite clearly see it in the Console?

(We aren't importing the key with Terraform or anything for this - just trying to get it to create an instance using a specified key pair so that it can be accessed with the key file after-the-fact.... it's worked for 10 people, but not the 11th.)

Comment: Maybe your student is set some env variables or aws/configure to use different account or region that what you think.

Comment: A good way to debug this would be to try outputting the values from the [`aws_caller_identity`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity) and the [`aws_region`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/region) data sources and then check that the key pair is available in that account and region.

Comment: Also you might want to consider using Terraform to upload the key pair itself to AWS so then you aren't relying on something out of band. If you were doing this for real you could get them to generate the key pair locally and then use the [`aws_key_pair`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair) resource to upload the public key to AWS. If it's just for training (ie not for production usage) you could also have Terraform dynamically generate the key pair as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792833/2291321. Note the final section of that answer.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've outputted these values and confirmed that the account ID is indeed the same account that has this key pair, we're in the right region, and the IAM role for the caller is the root account. I understand this is not a best practice solution, but it's just a lab to get students comfortable with Terraform. Unfortunately I'm still stumped as to why it can't find that this key pair is indeed in her account.