# Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am working on the main.tf file for creating a virtual machine in azure with remote execution and also I would like to create and download the SSH key .pem file in this file to access Linux VM.

main. tf file

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id =       var.tenant_id
 
}
# Create a resource group if it doesn't exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
    name     = var.resource_group
    location = var.resource_group_location

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myterraformnetwork" {
    name                = "myVnet"
    address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location            = "eastus"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "myterraformsubnet" {
    name                 = "mySubnet"
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myterraformnetwork.name
    address_prefixes       = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
    name                         = "myPublicIP"
    location                     = "eastus"
    resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myterraformnsg" {
    name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
    location            = "eastus"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name

    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
    name                      = "myNIC"
    location                  = "eastus"
    resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
        subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.myterraformsubnet.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}

# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
    network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id
    network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
    keepers = {
        # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
        resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
    }

    byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorageaccount" {
    name                        = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
    resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
    location                    = "eastus"
    account_tier                = "Standard"
    account_replication_type    = "LRS"

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
# Create (and display) an SSH key
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits = 2048
    }
    output "tls_private_key" { 
    value = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem 
    sensitive = true
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
    name                  = "myVM"
    location              = "eastus"
    resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name
    network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id]
    size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"

    os_disk {
        name              = "myOsDisk"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
    }

    source_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "18.04-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    disable_password_authentication = true

    admin_ssh_key {
    username = "azureuser"
    public_key     = tls_private_key.example_ssh.public_key_openssh
    }

    boot_diagnostics {
        storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint
    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo"
    }
}
resource "null_resource" "execute" {
connection {
    type        =   "ssh"
    agent       =   false
    user        =   "azureuser"
    host        =   azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
    private_key =   tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem
}
provisioner "file" {
  source    =   "./config"
  destination   =   "~/"
}
provisioner "remote-exec" {
 inline     = [
   "chmod 755 ~/scripts/*",
   "sudo sh ~/scripts/foreman_prerequisite_config.sh",
   ]
}
depends_on = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myterraformvm]
}
```

Facing the below error when using command  `terraform apply`

```
[0m[1mnull_resource.execute: Provisioning with 'file'...[0m[0m
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mfile provisioner error[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0m  with null_resource.execute,
[31m│[0m [0m  on main.tf line 184, in resource "null_resource" "execute":
[31m│[0m [0m 184: provisioner "file" [4m{[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0mhost for provisioner cannot be empty
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All I can see in the docs is that there is a note which says the public IP address resource is dynamic and its attributes are not available until attached to a NIC. Even though I see that you attached it to a NIC and attached that NIC to a VM, I would try with the data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/public_ip.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I need to change anything in my code as per your reference link? Also, it would be great if you assist me clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Azure provider documentation [1], when the public IP allocation type is `Dynamic`, you should use the `data` source to get the IP address:

```
data "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myterraformvm.resource_group_name
}
```

Then, in the `host` argument of the `null_resource` you should set the following:

```
host = data.azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
```

However, this might not fix the issue you have as it seems there is a problem with this version of Azure provider for Linux VMs [2]:

> In this release there's a known issue where the public_ip_address and public_ip_addresses fields may not be fully populated for Dynamic Public IP's.

The second part of the question was related to generating an SSH key which can be used later on to access a VM. In your question you have this code:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

output "tls_private_key" { 
    value = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem 
    sensitive = true
}
```

The `output` is not needed based on the answer you linked in the comments [3]. This can be used to create a private key in the same directory:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "local_file" "private_key_file" {
  content  = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem
  filename = "${path.root}/private-key.pem"
}
```

Then, in the `null_resource`, you should add the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "execute" {
  connection {
    type        =   "ssh"
    agent       =   false
    user        =   "azureuser"
    host        =   data.azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.ip_address
    private_key =   "${path.root}/private-key.pem"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      =  "./config"
    destination =  "~/"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
   inline     = [
     "chmod 755 ~/scripts/*",
     "sudo sh ~/scripts/foreman_prerequisite_config.sh",
   ]
  }
}
depends_on = [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.myterraformvm]
}
```

Note that you probably should not use the `tls_private_key` resource for production environments [4]:

> The private key generated by this resource will be stored unencrypted in your Terraform state file. Use of this resource for production deployments is not recommended. Instead, generate a private key file outside of Terraform and distribute it securely to the system where Terraform will be run.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/public_ip#example-usage-retrieve-the-dynamic-public-ip-of-a-new-vm

[2] [https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#:~:text=In%20this%20release%20there%27s%20a%20known%20issue%20where%20the%20public_ip_address%20and%20public_ip_addresses%20fields%20may%20not%20be%20fully%20populated%20for%20Dynamic%20Public%20IP%27s](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#:%7E:text=In%20this%20release%20there%27s%20a%20known%20issue%20where%20the%20public_ip_address%20and%20public_ip_addresses%20fields%20may%20not%20be%20fully%20populated%20for%20Dynamic%20Public%20IP%27s).

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/67379867/8343484

[4] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key

Comment: If that works, I would appreciate accepting this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works for me. I would like to download the tls_private_key_pem (.pem) key file generated by Terraform with help of the module. [1] (https://github.com/hashicorp-modules/tls-private-key/blob/master/main.tf) and [2] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743220/how-do-i-create-an-ssh-key-in-terraform?rq=1#:~:text=18-,Feb%2C%202022%20Update%3A,-The%20code%20below)

Comment: Could you please help me with the above issue mentioned comment.

Comment: That is a different question not related to the original problem, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, But I asked this along with the original question too
.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll update the answer then.

Comment: I have changed the codes as you described above. but it does not work for me. The key file is not saved in the location. any idea or suggestions? `command = "echo '${self.private_key_pem}' > ${path.root}/private-key.pem"` this is not working properly.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows. However, I tried to use direct folder path, ~/ and ./ (current directory) instead ${path.root}.

Comment: I updated the answer which hopefully will help.

Comment: Superb really I appreciate your effort and time. Thanks a lot. Its works perfectly.

Comment: Always happy to help. :)