# Error: remote-exec provisioner error: host for provisioner cannot be empty

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create 2 virtual machines under a Load balancer and I am using remote-exec provisioner to install nginx server to both VM. I cannot use azurerm_public_ip properly. It doesnt pass the IP address to the host connection block of my remote-exec provisioner.

Below is my code:

```
# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test-rg-nginx" {
  name     = var.rgname
  location = var.rg_location
  #name     = "test-tf-test"
  #location = "East US"
}


# Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test-vnet-nginx" {
  name                = var.vnetname
  address_space       = ["10.66.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  #name                = "test-tf-vnet"
}


# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "test-subnet-nginx" {
  name                 = var.subnetname
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test-vnet-nginx.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.66.1.0/24"]
}


# Public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test-publicIP-VM" {
  count = var.vm_count
  name  = "${var.publicIP-VMname}${count.index}"


  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test-publicIP-LB" {
  name                = var.publicIP-LBname
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}




#Create Load Balancer
resource "azurerm_lb" "test-lb-nginx" {
  name                = var.lbname
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name


  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "${var.publicIP-LBname}-frontend"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-LB.id
  }
}


resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "lb_backendIPpool" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.test-lb-nginx.id
  name            = "BackEndAddressPool"
}


resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "http_probe" {
  name            = "http_probe"
  protocol        = "Tcp"
  port            = 80
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.test-lb-nginx.id
  #resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
}


resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "http_rule" {
  name                           = "http-rule"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${var.publicIP-LBname}-frontend"
  #backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lb_backendIPpool.id
  probe_id        = azurerm_lb_probe.http_probe.id
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.test-lb-nginx.id
  #resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "backendpoolAssoc" {
  count                   = var.vm_count
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.test-nic[count.index].id
  ip_configuration_name   = "${var.nic-ip-configname}${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lb_backendIPpool.id
}


# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test-nic" {
  count = var.vm_count
  #name = var.nicname
  name                = "${var.nicname}-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name


  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.nic-ip-configname}${count.index}"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.test-subnet-nginx.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM[count.index].id
  }
}




# Network Security Group and Security rules
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "test-nsg-nginx" {
  name                = var.nsgname
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name


  security_rule {
    name                       = "HTTPS"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "443"
    source_address_prefixes    = var.address-list
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "HTTP"
    priority                   = 101
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefixes    = var.address-list
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH-Inbound"
    priority                   = 102
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefixes    = var.address-list
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}


# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "test-sgConnect" {
  count                     = var.vm_count
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.test-nic[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.test-nsg-nginx.id
}


resource "azurerm_availability_set" "avset" {
  name                         = "avset"
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  platform_fault_domain_count  = 2
  platform_update_domain_count = 2
  managed                      = true
}


#Create VM
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "test-linux" {
  count                 = var.vm_count
  name                  = "${var.vm-linux}-${count.index}"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
  availability_set_id   = azurerm_availability_set.avset.id
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.test-nic[count.index].id]
  size                  = var.vm-size




  os_disk {
    name                 = "myOsdisk-${count.index}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }


  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
    sku       = "22_04-lts-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  computer_name                   = var.admin-user
  admin_username                  = var.admin-user
  disable_password_authentication = true
  #wait_for_address = true


  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = var.admin-user
    public_key = file("${path.module}/connection/linux-pub0.pub")
  }


  depends_on = [
    azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM
  ]


 


data "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
  count = var.vm_count
  name                = azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM[count.index].name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
}


resource "null_resource" "default-web-server" {
  count = var.vm_count


  provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install -y nginx",
      "sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/",
      "sudo chown -R ${var.admin-user}:${var.admin-user} /var/www/html/",
      "sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html"
    ]
    }
  Timeouts{
     read = “5m”
}
  connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.admin-user
      private_key = file("${path.module}/connection/linux-priv0.pem")
      host = "${data.azurerm_public_ip.publicip[count.index].ip_address}"
      #host = data.azurerm_public_ip.publicip[count.index].fqdn
      #host        = azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM[count.index].ip_address
      timeout        = "2m"
    }




  provisioner "file" {
    #connection = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.test-linux.connection
    source      = "${path.module}/WebContents/server-contents.html"
    destination = "/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html"
  }


   triggers = {
    timestamp = timestamp()
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.test-linux,
    azurerm_network_interface.test-nic,
    azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM,
    data.azurerm_public_ip.publicip
  ]
}
```

I have tried to use data to pass the IP address but I still get and error. This is the link that I used: [Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292185/error-host-for-provisioner-cannot-be-emptyhost) for provisioner cannot be empty

The error that I am encountering is this:
Error: remote-exec provisioner error
host for provisioner cannot be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issues by using the public_ip_address parameter of the azurerm_virtual machine:

host        = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.test-linux[count.index].public_ip_address

data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test-linux" {
count = var.vm_count
name                  = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.test-linux[count.index].name
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg-nginx.name
}

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the IP address of the network interface associated with each virtual machine, use the data `azurerm_network_interface` block.

*I made below changes to your code.*

```
data "azurerm_network_interface"  "test-nic" {
 count = var.vm_count 
 name = azurerm_network_interface.test-nic[count.index].name } 
resource "null_resource"  "default-web-server" { 
count = var.vm_count 
provisioner "remote-exec" { 
inline = [ 
"sudo apt-get update", 
"sudo apt-get install -y nginx", 
"sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/", 
"sudo chown -R ${var.admin-user}:${var.admin-user} /var/www/html/", 
"sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html" 
] 
} 
connection { 
type = "ssh" 
user = var.admin-user 
private_key = file("${path.module}/connection/linux-xxxx.pem") 
host = data.azurerm_network_interface.test-nic[count.index].private_ip_address 
timeout = "2m" 
} 
provisioner "file" { 
source = "xxxx" 
destination = "xxxx" 
} 
triggers = { 
timestamp = timestamp() 
} 
depends_on = [ azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.test-linux, azurerm_network_interface.test-nic, azurerm_public_ip.test-publicIP-VM, data.azurerm_public_ip.publicip ] }
```

*After making these changes, I was able to successfully initialize terraform with a valid configuration.*

[image]

*If still the issue persists,*

Calling `ssh` from `local-exec` might help in fixing by allowing you to provide additional connection parameters to the output.

Refer [terraform hashicorp issues](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-remote-exec-provisioner-error/37393/3) & [Provisioners terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) for more relevant information.

And this is an intermittent issue as per the [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21369) issues.

Comment: This will not work for me as I need the public IP to connect via SSH not the private IP.